# SOLR RuntimeException during indexing: how to write document id to log?

Tags: java, solr, jetty

We are indexing millions of documents. We use Solr 3.1 and Jetty. I enabled logging in Jetty as described here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LoggingInDefaultJettySetup

For some fulltexts we get exceptions and therefore logs like this one:

```
<record>
  <date>2012-09-04T15:55:16</date>
  <millis>1346766916578</millis>
  <sequence>0</sequence>
  <logger>org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</class>
  <method>log</method>
  <thread>10</thread>
  <message>java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.io.CharConversionException] Invalid UTF-8 character 0xd835(a surrogate character)  at c
har #1144, byte #127)
        at com.ctc.wstx.util.ExceptionUtil.throwRuntimeException(ExceptionUtil.java:18)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:731)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3657)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:809)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.readDoc(XMLLoader.java:287)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:77)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)

</message>
</record>
```

It would be great to also log the sent document id. How can we do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get Jetty to log the ID?  It is unlikely that you will be able to log it through Jetty as the XML in the request can't be parsed in order to get to the ID value.  Notice the stack trace informs that the XMLLoader.readDoc() method never gets past line 287.  Here's the code for that class (for your version):
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_1/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/XMLLoader.java?revision=1086927&view=markup

The relevant section:

```
 SolrInputDocument readDoc(XMLStreamReader parser) throws XMLStreamException {
264     SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
265     
266     String attrName = "";
267     for (int i = 0; i < parser.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
268     attrName = parser.getAttributeLocalName(i);
269     if ("boost".equals(attrName)) {
270     doc.setDocumentBoost(Float.parseFloat(parser.getAttributeValue(i)));
271     } else {
272     XmlUpdateRequestHandler.log.warn("Unknown attribute doc/@" + attrName);
273     }
274     }
275     
276     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
277     String name = null;
278     float boost = 1.0f;
279     boolean isNull = false;
280     while (true) {
281     int event = parser.next();
282     switch (event) {
283     // Add everything to the text
284     case XMLStreamConstants.SPACE:
285     case XMLStreamConstants.CDATA:
286     case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
287     text.append(parser.getText());
```

The Solr document has not yet been built, so there's no real way to get to the records ID field.

The workaround is to have your indexer script check the status codes of the Solr responses and write the record ID to a log if status is not 0 (success).  Likewise if you are using Java or PHP or a language that can trap exceptions you can catch those too and write out to log.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will amend my indexer script.

Comment: You're welcome.  We're also in the middle of indexing millions of docs.  It's definitely not a trivial undertaking.  Best of luck.